# odd error doing RSA encryption then decryption on an AES key

Tags: python, security

the following code

```
    key = sec.generateAESKey()
    print(key, ': ', len(key))
    
    key = b64encode(key)
    print(key, ': ', len(key))
    
    key = sec.encryptAsymmetric(str(key))
    key = sec.decryptAsymmetric(key)
    print(key, ': ', len(key))
    
    key = b64decode(key)
    print(key, ': ', len(key))
```

outputs

b'\xae\xfe\x8b\xb8\xbe\x86=\xe8\x979/@\xf58\xf9\x95' :  16

b'rv6LuL6GPeiXOS9A9Tj5lQ==' :  24

b'rv6LuL6GPeiXOS9A9Tj5lQ==' :  27

b'n\xbb\xfa.\xe2\xfa\x18\xf7\xa2\\xe4\xbd\x03\xd4\xe3\xe6T' :  17

as you can see something is going wrong with the asymmetric encryption and decryption as the key gains 3 bytes prior to b64decoding and 1 byte after that

base functions are:

```
from Cryptodome.PublicKey import RSA
from Cryptodome.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Random import get_random_bytes
from Cryptodome.Hash import SHA256
from base64 import b64decode
from base64 import b64encode
import re

# important global vars, don't need to re-generate these
public_key_plain = open("public.pem").read()
public_key = RSA.import_key(public_key_plain)
private_key = RSA.import_key(open("private.pem").read())

# constants
KEY_SIZE = 16
AUTH_TOKEN_EXPIRY = 15 # minutes

# encrypt using our public key
# data should be in a string format
def encryptAsymmetric(data):
    # convert the data to utf-8
    data = data.encode("utf-8")
    # generate the cipher
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(public_key, hashAlgo=SHA256)
    # encrypt
    return b64encode(cipher.encrypt(data))

# decrypt some cipher text using our private key
def decryptAsymmetric(ciphertext):
    # generate the cipher
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key, hashAlgo=SHA256)
    # decrypt
    return cipher.decrypt(b64decode(ciphertext)).decode()

# generates a key for aes
def generateAESKey():
    return get_random_bytes(KEY_SIZE)
```

the code that generated this error up above is part of some unit tests being written on the backend. These functions work perfectly fine when it is the client that is doing the asymmetric encryption and the server that is decrypting. For some reason it's failing here but i cannot see why.
if anyone can see whats wrong with the asymmetric encryption and decryption and why it's changing the key that would be really helpful.
thanks in advance

Comment: This is not the correct way to transmit the AES key with RSA. There is RSA-KEM for this.

Comment: Can you separate out and print the `key` variable after doing `str(key)`?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes it looks like the str(key) is where the extra bytes are being added on

Comment: the encryptAsymmetric function takes strings not byte arrays

Comment: to change that would mean changing the decrypt function which would break the functioning client-server interaction

Comment: thanks @MaartenBodewes that fixed it

Comment: b64 encoded: b'WyVC94Z+tr6mtFyb7SMsTQ==' :  24
after str():b'WyVC94Z+tr6mtFyb7SMsTQ==' :  27

Comment: Never mind, I've seen documentation that it is the BOM indeed. Let's delete some now unnecesssary comments!

Comment: I'd like to try this myself but I don't have your .pem files. Can you share them?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Can you share that documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `str()` method adds 3 bytes to the already base 64 encoded data.

The base 64 encoder returns ASCII encoded bytes. So instead of just returning a string (which you would use for text) the base 64 encoder returns *bytes*. Now if you convert them to a string then it may see that it *just* contains ASCII. However, it seems like the standard encoder within Python always adds 3 bytes as it regenerates the full string as the the `__str__` method is used on the `bytes` instance.

Just decoding the bytes as ASCII using `str(key, encoding='ascii')`  seems to remove this problem. It is however better to use the explicit `decode` method for this.

---

Answer edited because of this [superb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63420938/589259) answer. I guess I should have had that other look at the actual bytes after all.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that base 64 is explicitly meant to convert bytes to text. The fact that it still output bytes instead of a string is something that is a leftover from old times and it annoys me as heck. It's especially stupid if your target text is not ASCII compatible (e.g. UTF-16). Outputting BOM is also that you'd rather avoid by now (the encoding `utf-8-sig` seems to solve that). And finally I'd say it is a bug that the base 64 decoder fails on the BOM - however that's lucky for you since you really don't want those extra 3 bytes anyway :)

Comment: There's no BOM here. See my answer.

Comment: @superbrain There is also something like deliberately misunderstanding an answer, but I've adjusted the wording.

Comment: Wasn't that wording. I just didn't think that doing something the *right* way is *removing* a problem, but that doing something the *wrong* way is *causing* a problem. But I just realized that I had the wrong perspective. Instead of being in a "neutral" position (like before using one way or the other), the question already put us in the problem position. And from there, switching indeed removes it. Apologies. Though I do think the rewording made it better :-)

Comment: NP, thanks for helping me understand the issue with the array and `__str__`, that was very useful (it compares with  `println(byte[])` in Java really). It's a bit weird that there are some BOM specific problems in python (also in Java, possibly BOM **is** the problem), and that there was exactly a 3 char difference, that surely wrong footed me.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this your way as I don't have your .pem files, but I can like this:

```
>>> key = b'rv6LuL6GPeiXOS9A9Tj5lQ=='
>>> print(key, ': ', len(key))
b'rv6LuL6GPeiXOS9A9Tj5lQ==' :  24

>>> key = str(key)
>>> print(key, ': ', len(key))
b'rv6LuL6GPeiXOS9A9Tj5lQ==' :  27
```

The three extra characters are simply the `b'` at the start and the `'` at the end. You'll see it if you print the representation using `repr` instead:

```
>>> key = b'rv6LuL6GPeiXOS9A9Tj5lQ=='
>>> print(repr(key), ': ', len(key))
b'rv6LuL6GPeiXOS9A9Tj5lQ==' :  24

>>> key = str(key)
>>> print(repr(key), ': ', len(key))
"b'rv6LuL6GPeiXOS9A9Tj5lQ=='" :  27
```

In the original key, the `b'` and `'` are **not** part of the `bytes`-string, they just show that it's a `bytes`-string and its borders. Just like the `"` around the `str`-string are not part of that string. But in *that* string, the `b'` and `'` **are** part of the string.

Not sure why you convert your `bytes` to `str`, but you shouldn't use `str(key)`. I'd use its `decode()` method. Then it's all good, you have a `str`-string without those extra characters:

```
>>> key = b'rv6LuL6GPeiXOS9A9Tj5lQ=='
>>> print(repr(key), ': ', len(key))
b'rv6LuL6GPeiXOS9A9Tj5lQ==' :  24

>>> key = key.decode()
>>> print(repr(key), ': ', len(key))
'rv6LuL6GPeiXOS9A9Tj5lQ==' :  24
```

Comment: interesting. that looks like it would have solved the problem as well, i'll have to try it out at some point. seems really weird that str(bytes) would have such a troublesome resultant string

Comment: @bahijzeineh Nah, that's just its job. Get a nice string representation of whatever object you give it. Without such extra characters, you wouldn't be able to distinguish `bytes`s from `str`s. Plus it's not even `str` that does it. That just uses the `bytes`'s own `__str__` method to get its string representation. Try calling `b'foo'.__str__()`, you'll get `"b'foo'"`. Though when given an `encoding` argument, `str` behaves differently and tries to decode instead. My `key.decode()` is equivalent to Maarten's `str(key, encoding='ascii')` here, I just prefer it for its brevity and explicitness.